# Add a script for a specific choice

Tags: powershell

I want to add a another (small) script for the main script who has choices. How can I do that ?

The script I want to add:

```
*$shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$desktop = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
$shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut("$desktop\Jauns Notepad.lnk")
$shortcut.TargetPath = "notepad.exe"
$shortcut.IconLocation = "%windir%\system32\imageres.dll 98"
$shortcut.Save()*
```

And the main script:

```
do {
    do {
        write-host ""
        write-host "1 - Selection 1"
        write-host "2 - Selection 2"
        write-host ""
        write-host "0 - Exit"
        write-host ""
        write-host -nonewline "Type your choice and press Enter: "

        $choice = read-host

        write-host ""

        $ok = $choice -match '^[abcdx]+$'

        if ( -not $ok) { write-host "Invalid selection" }
    } until ( $ok )

    switch -Regex ( $choice ) {
        "1"
        {
            write-host "You entered '1'"
        }

        "2"
        {
            write-host "You entered '2'"
        }
    }
} until ( $choice -match "0" )
```

Please somebody help out!

Comment: While not the best approach have you tried copy and paste. That code does stand on its own.

Comment: You validation process is also flawed. 1 evaluates to a invalid selection.

Comment: You don't have to re-invent the wheel. To add a menu with choices, follow [this tutorial](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730939.aspx).

Comment: Add your extra script into the main script as a function - powershell handles this fine. Question isn't very clear as to what you are trying to achieve either